# Angular Handling common code in seperate javascript module

Tags: angular

Here I am trying to make an experiment, hence seeks input on advantage and disadvantage of this approach.

We have 3 projects(separate angular SPAs).
They use some common stuff, let say logging for now.
Since I don't want to maintain 3 different copy of same code and also my project don't have versioning issue.

So I created a javascript module which exports a LoggingService like this.

In Logger.ts file(This file is out of the scr folder of angular in separate folder externallib)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
    export class LoggerService{
        Log(message){
        console.debug(message)
    }
}
```

And inside my angular module what I did was I imported this file and registered as a service.

In app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './../../externallib/Logger' //**This is my custom library**

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
    ],
    providers: [ LoggerService ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
    constructor()
    {
    }
}
```

And in my component I am calling this service LoggerService.
This works perfectly fine.

Please provide me with the drawback of this approach.

Also: Versioning of this common code is not a requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question may be too prone to opionated answers for s.o but i'll risk answering anyways. I think this is fine if you work alone. Drawbacks maybe:

- breaking changes in the ext lib (due to no versioning)
- someone (you) moves one or the other to another path

Doing a private npm module would fix these.

CLI can generate a library project now too, using ng-packagr (which is already awesome on it's own) internally, you might want to look up changes in NG 6.

Comment: Have fun, it's awesome :)

Comment: i tried that and yes its awesome. But its available with Angular6 and not 5. I will try with ng-packagr which is actually working behind the scene of "ng g library" and will post in case I have something useful.

Comment: For Angular V5 ng-packagr is the best solution i guess I have successfully implemented and now using in our application. It turns out to be the only option for this requirement. Also you dont have to publish it to npm also and still manage it like a package.

Answer (score 0):

Drawback: If your Library is not commited into Your project then it will not compile when someone clone your project from git. (you need write in documentation that someone must put LoggerService into proper directory 'near your project' by hand)

Better approach: Create separate git repository of this library and set up it in your project as git SUBMODULE in directory e.g `./src/commons/services/LoggerService`

Comment: Agree, but that concern is already taken care of. So here I am mostly interested in disadvantages from angular perspective because I am using angular decorator  in a file which is not part of angular project.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Drawback: putting some source files outside `src` directory can be counter-intuitive for other angular programmers (angular projects usually have their code in that directory).